# Is it legal to use minecraft and minecraft mods in a for profit video?

Tags: copyright, youtube, video-games

Is it legal to make youtube videos about historical events using minecraft and minecraft mods? How to ensure the rule of fair-use is fulfilled when using these games and fan-made contents?

Comment: This is a question about fair use, which is always difficult.  But mostly you should make this less like asking for legal advice.  Rephrasing it into the third person would probably help.